# WebView2 ExecuteScript not returning

Tags: delphi, webview2

I have encountered a **very rare case** where it seems ExecuteScript does not return?

```
FWebBrowser.ExecuteScript('document.documentElement.outerHTML',
        procedure (const AStrResult: string)
        begin
          // never returns here
          TmpGetDocumentAsStr := AStrResult;
          TmpCS.Acquire;
          TmpExecuted := True;
          TmpCS.Release;
        end
      );
```

So my code underneath waiting for TmpExecuted to be true (loop with checking value and sleeping) just continues forever.

Now, I can of course exit myself efter 100000 miliseconds or whatever. But I would prefer if ExecuteScript would return itself after x amount of time.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure what component you are using, because TEdgeBrowser does not have any ExecuteScript method with two parameters. But as a general thought, we have solved some problems by wrapping the script text in encodeURI(), so that any special characters become "safe". So you could perhaps try ExecuteScript('encodeURI(document.documentElement.outerHTML)')

Answer (score 0):

If you call a WebView2 async method, then block that same UI thread with a loop that sleeps or otherwise isn't processing window messages then the WebView2 async method will never complete. You'll need to return back to the message loop for the WebView2 to receive the message that the async method has completed. This is described more in the [WebView2 Threading Model document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/threading-model#block-the-ui-thread).

Comment: The code running the above code is running in a worker non-UI thread. So while WebView2 is running in non-blocked UI thread, the worker thread simply waits (sleep/wakeup-check etc.) The reasons for this is long-winded but essentially it is an already existing multi-threaded crawler engine that is built around worker threads. Somtimes the work threads just (these days) need to witch over to a browser engine to handle AJAX etc.